# Use unix file behavior in windows node.js

Tags: node.js, windows, unix, filesystems

I develop an app in Windows using Node.js. I deploy on a Unix system. Windows has case insensitive file handling, while Unix has case sensitive file handling. This causes errors in deployment, as it is easy to make file naming consistency errors.

For example:

```
<img src="Image.png" />
```

with an `image.png` (note the capital i) present in the project causes a 404 when the app is served from a unix system.

How can I simulate the unix behavior in windows, such that I catch these errors in development-time?

Comment: Name your files properly? It's easier to enforce a naming constraint than try to guess the correct file path across environments. You could even automate the lowercasing of file names as part of your build process - the same goes for user input files, just lowercase them on the go.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! The goal is indeed to name the file properly. Now, if I would just get a tool to help me with this...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this would work, but if you launch your app from the command line, you can use the [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) console on Windows to emulate a Linux environment.